# Google App Flexible Java Logging Not Working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have a simple servlet as below. And I'm unable to see any of System.out or log.info in the gcloud logs. I used `gcloud app logs tail -s my-app-name`. I only see logs for GET and favicon. Please help to enable logs in my google cloud app.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "Home", description = "Write low order IP address to response", urlPatterns = "/")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeServlet.class.getName());
    Connection conn;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
            log("FINE is loggable.");
            System.out.println("This is System Out. FINE is loggable");
            logger.fine("Received GET request");
        } else {
            log("FINE is not loggable");
            System.out.println("This is System Out. FINE is not loggable");
            logger.severe("Received GET request");
        }
        String path = req.getRequestURI();
        if (path.startsWith("/favicon.ico")) {
            return; // ignore the request for favicon.ico
        }

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        String userIp = req.getRemoteAddr();
        out.print("Your IP is: " + userIp);
        log("responded GET request from: " + userIp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command this way:

```
gcloud app logs tail --service=my-service --version=my-app-version
```

in order to specify the service and version, then see If you're not really getting all the logs. See a list of all options [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail). Also you can see all your logs by going to **Stackdriver -> Logging -> Logs**:

[image]

Once there, you can filter the logs by app version:

[image]

Also be aware that depending on the request you make, sometimes you'll only see certain kind of logs. I pasted your code in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart) for app engine flexible and I got this:

```
    ...........

    2017-12-18 09:40:07 my-service[my-app-version]  "GET /favicon.ico" 200
    2017-12-18 09:40:07 my-service[my-app-version]  "GET /" 200
    2017-12-18 09:40:07 my-service[my-app-version]  "GET /favicon.ico" 200
    2017-12-18 09:40:08 my-service[my-app-version]  "GET /" 200
    2017-12-18 09:40:13 my-service[my-app-version]  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.root: com.example.appengine.gettingstartedjava.helloworld.HomeServlet: FINE is not loggable
    2017-12-18 09:40:13 my-service[my-app-version]  com.example.appengine.gettingstartedjava.helloworld.HomeServlet: Received GET request
    2017-12-18 09:40:13 my-service[my-app-version]  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.root: com.example.appengine.gettingstartedjava.helloworld.HomeServlet: responded GET request from: 35.187.117.231
    2017-12-18 09:40:13 my-service[my-app-version]  This is System Out. FINE is not loggable
    2017-12-18 09:40:15 my-service[my-app-version]  This is System Out. FINE is not loggable

..........
```

In addition to this, you can use the [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries). First add this to your POM dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then use the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart) and paste this code in the HelloServlet.java. Your code would look like this:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello, world - Flex Servlet");

    Logging logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    String logName = "My-log";

    String text = "Hello World";

    LogEntry entry = LogEntry.newBuilder(StringPayload.of(text)).setSeverity(Severity.ERROR).setLogName(logName)
            .setResource(MonitoredResource.newBuilder("global").build()).build();

    logging.write(Collections.singleton(entry));

    System.out.printf("Logged: %s%n", text);

}
```

You can see this result in Stackdriver:

[image]